# SQL Server - adding Created Date to a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I've inserted few rows into a table, and after that I wanted to add `CreatedDate` column. I added it by setting a default constraint on it. Created Date is getting loaded for all the rows I inserted after setting the constraint. But how can we get the date populated for other older rows of data?

Comment: You can't (at least not automatically). The default constraint won't backdate and find some way to get the date you inserted that row.

Comment: Well, since you don't know when those previous rows were inserted... you can just force a date with an UPDATE statement with a single date, or what ever similar method you want.

Answer (score 0):

What date are you trying to add to the older entries? Their create date, or today's date? If you just want to add today's date you can do a UPDATE  with GetDate() on all the old data rows.

Comment: Yes, I should see "Their created date"

Comment: Is there anywhere in the current table that shows that date?

Answer (score 0):

> But how can we get the date populated for other older rows of data?

This is not easily achievable, and may not be possible at all.

If you happen to know when the older rows were entered, you can add that date-time with a manual UPDATE query.

If you need to find it, and your database is using transactional backup/recovery model, you can buy a transaction log reader and go through your transaction logs to find the original INSERT commands and when they were executed.

If you can't do that, then there is no possible way to find the original "create date" of the rows that were already entered.